# Using iText 7 and Powershell to write text/lines/boxes to PDF

Tags: powershell, itext7

I've managed to create a blank PDF using PowerShell and iText 7. I would like to write some text, lines and boxes to the newly created PDF, but can't find any information on how to do this. Here is what I have so far, which is my attempt to write text to the created PDF. Any help or direction to help would be appreciated.

```
[string] $pdfDocuFilename = "C:\test\meow4.pdf"
$pdfWriter = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new($pdfDocuFilename)
$pdf = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($pdfWriter)
$pdf.AddNewPage()
$Paragraph = [iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph]::new()
[iText.Layout.Element.Text] $PDFText = "Hello World"
$Paragraph.Add($PDFText)
$pdf.Close()
```

Comment: Have you tried `$pdf.add($PDFText)` or `$pdf.add($Paragraph)`?

Comment: I just did, they both fail with this error "Method invocation failed because [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument] does not contain a method named 'Add'."

Comment: Looks like you need to create a `Document` in addition to a `PdfDocument`. Check out this tutorial https://riptutorial.com/itext

Comment: Have you seen this article [iText / iTextSharp / Powershell / checkboxes](http://www.somethingtoscrollthrough.com/2016/06/itext-itextsharp-powershell-checkboxes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this aswell.
Yet I haven't figured it all out, but I could manage to add text with the following code.

```
#import the modules
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\temp\itext.kernel.dll")
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Common.Logging.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\Common.Logging.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\itext.io.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\itext.layout.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"

$pdfname = "C:\temp\test.pdf"

$pdfwriter = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new($pdfname)
$pdf = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($pdfwriter)
$document = [iText.Layout.Document]::new($pdf)
$paragraph = [iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph]::new($document)
$text = [itext.Layout.Element.Text]::new("Hello World")

$paragraph.add($text)
$document.add($paragraph)
```

but this gives me a pdf file that looks like this:
iText.Layout.DocumentHello World

however when I change it to add a paragraph like the line below, it works fine.

```
$document.Add([iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph]::new("Hello World"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working Hello World example.
Note: the iText packages are in a folder name "lib" at the source file location

```
# $PSScriptRoot gets the source file location
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\Common.Logging.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\Common.Logging.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\itext.io.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\itext.kernel.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\itext.kernel.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$PSScriptRoot\lib\itext.layout.dll"

$desc = "$PSScriptRoot\hello_world.pdf"
$writer = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter]::new($desc)
$pdf = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument]::new($writer)
$document = [iText.Layout.Document]::new($pdf)
$document.Add([iText.Layout.Element.Paragraph]::new("Hello World!"))
```